# Referencing named groups in look-around (Python 2.x)

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have a pattern that matches for *multiple* key/value pairs, and the key/value strings can be delimited by any characters, then the groups of key/value can also be delimited, just **not by the same character**.

I figured out how to allow dynamic delimiters, and restrict the same delimiter from being used twice. EG:

```
\w+(?P<kv_delim>[:;|])\d+(?P<g_delim>(?!(?P=kv_delim))[:;|])\w(?P=kv_delim)\d(?P=g_delim)?
```

[You can view the regex101.com example here](https://regex101.com/r/qC7hQ2/3). And it works great, the problem comes when using either of the two named groups in a *positive look-behind*.

Lets say the string is

> `foo:1;r:2`

The "key/value delimiter" (named group: `kv_delim`) is the `:`, then the "group delimiter" (named group: `grp_delim`) is the `;`

What im trying to do is dynamically match the `:` and `;`, then in a look-around statement, look for `foo<kv_delim>`, or `bar<kv_delim>`.

If I hard-code the delimiters (in the look-around), [you can see it works](https://regex101.com/r/uM6bL8/3). But if I try to reference the named-group `kv_delim` within the look-around statement, [you can see it throws errors](https://regex101.com/r/bA6dM6/2). I get the error:

> Subpattern references are not allowed within a lookbehind assertion

Which is whats kickin my butt

Anybody have a way to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `.` instead of a backreference.

Comment: Just split things up across a few lines. Trying to parse a string with a single regex like this usually makes for incomprehensible and unmaintainable code.

Comment: The [documentation clearly states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for both negative and positive look-behind assertions that "The contained pattern must only match strings of some fixed length".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, really? You might be looking for `\G` which is only supported by the newer `regex` module.

Answer (score 0):

Summing up what has already been said: the point is that the length of the pattern is unknown when you put backreferences into a lookbehind that [must be fixed-width](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) at design time. The newer [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) has no limitations regarding the lookbehind length, so, the current workaround is to use this module with your regex:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = "foo:1;r:2"
>>> rx = r"\w+(?P<kv_delim>[:;|])\d+(?P<g_delim>(?!(?P=kv_delim))[:;|])\w(?P=kv_delim)\d(?P=g_delim)?"
>>> print(regex.findall(rx, s))
[(':', ';')]
>>> print([m.group() for m in regex.finditer(rx, s)])
['foo:1;r:2']
>>>
```